# NoSuchElementExists Error... is it because there is a for each inside the iterator?

Tags: java

NoSuchElementExists Error, along with some AbstractList warning... is it because there is a for each inside the iterator?

```
while(it.hasNext()) {
                for(Square s : ChessBoard.BOARD_SQUARES) {
                    int[] move = it.next();
                    // Match moves to squares
                    if(Arrays.equals(s.getPosition(), move)) {
                        // Remove moves if they are capturing your own pieces
                        if(s.hasPiece()) {
                            boolean capturingYourOwnPiece = ((s.getPiece()).getTeamColor()).equals(ChessBoard.getTurn());
                            if(capturingYourOwnPiece) {
                                it.remove();
                            }
                        // Remove diagonal moves if no adjacent pieces
                        } else {
                            if(move[0]!=0) {
                                it.remove();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // If it passes tests, then add it to the official list
                    // of legal moves
                    listOfLegalSquares.add(ChessBoard.getSquare(move));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `it.next()` inside a for loop which means that it potentially gets called multiple times for each `it.hasNext()`

The correct use of an Iterator is to call `it.next()` once for every `it.hasNext()`

Answer (score 0):

ideally you should call .next only once inside while or should chk hasNext before doing it